# How can I enable TTY console?

Tags: linux, kernel, tty, console, framebuffer

I'm running Linux (Debian 10) on a Chromebook (Eve) using a stock Chrome OS kernel (4.4.x) with minor modifications. Everything runs (mostly) fine except that TTY console cannot be accessed via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>, which does switch framebuffers as intended (*i.e.* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> switches to DM and <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> switches to desktop), but there doesn't seem to be any framebuffer for TTY emulation to display on (the screen just freezes upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> but desktop can be recovered just by <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>). Given that no log is displayed at boot, I'm guessing it's a kernel configuration issue. Relevant driver options related to TTY, console, and framebuffer are already enabled in the kernel configuration, and `tty` devices are listed in `/dev`. I tried compiling the Chrome OS kernel using stock Debian 10 configurations (for what overlap and default configuration for those that don't) and the TTY console did become available (but obviously a bunch of other things didn't work), so it isn't something that was written out of the Chrome OS kernel.

I compared the stock configurations between Eve and Debian and noted where different options are chosen on the same configuration items (there are 532 of these) and noted the following differences:

```
CONFIG_ITEM                         Debian      Eve
CONFIG_AGP_AMD64                    y           is not set
CONFIG_AGP_SIS                      y           is not set
CONFIG_AGP_VIA                      y           is not set
CONFIG_VGA_SWITCHEROO               y           is not set
CONFIG_DRM_FBDEV_EMULATION          y           is not set
CONFIG_DRM_LOAD_EDID_FIRMWARE       y           is not set
CONFIG_DRM_DP_CEC                   y           is not set
CONFIG_DRM_VGEM                     is not set  y
CONFIG_DRM_UDL                      is not set  y
CONFIG_DRM_CIRRUS_QEMU              is not set  m
CONFIG_FIRMWARE_EDID                y           is not set
CONFIG_FB_BOOT_VESA_SUPPORT         y           is not set
CONFIG_FB_CFB_FILLRECT              y           is not set
CONFIG_FB_CFB_COPYAREA              y           is not set
CONFIG_FB_CFB_IMAGEBLIT             y           is not set
CONFIG_FB_SYS_FILLRECT              y           is not set
CONFIG_FB_SYS_COPYAREA              y           is not set
CONFIG_FB_SYS_IMAGEBLIT             y           is not set
CONFIG_FB_SYS_FOPS                  y           is not set
CONFIG_FB_TILEBLITTING              y           is not set
CONFIG_FB_VESA                      y           is not set
CONFIG_FB_EFI                       y           is not set
CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE_ROTATION y           is not set
```

But nothing changes after I compiled the kernel with these setting copied from Debian to the stock Eve configuration. Something else is amiss, and help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a chromebook to check -- maybe the virtual consoles are not configured at all, similarly to android phones and other embedded linux systems. But maybe it's just the init system which isn't spawning a shell on them. Would `openvt -fc 12` (as root) followed by `Ctrl-Alt-F12` do anything, like showing you a prompt?

Comment: @user414777 same thing, the screen freezes, but recoverable via <Ctrl><Alt>F2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After noticing that /dev/fb0 didn't exist despite having loaded `fbcon` and a framebuffer device module, I figured it out:

1. Build `i915` as a loadable module instead of built-in and make sure that legacy `fbdev` support is enabled. (Building it as a loadable module is perhaps not necessary, I only did it to ensure I could blacklist/unload `i915`, but the key is to select legacy `fbdev` support.)
2. Enable framebuffer console (`fbcon`) and build it as a module.
3. Ensure that tty is also enabled.
4. Edit `/src/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915_drv.c` and remove or comment out all `if` loops that refer to conflicting framebuffer modules (just search for "conflict", on 4.4.250-R89 kernel source there are 3 of these loops), otherwise you might encounter an error during make. Apparently the `i915` driver for ChromeOS doesn't want you to have a framebuffer console.
5. Build kernel and modules. Install to Linux.
6. Add `fbcon` to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` to load them at boot (they do not load by default). Alternatively, you can load it manually when you need to use TTY emulation.
7. Update initramfs and grub. Reboot. You should be able to see kernel boot messages and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> to access TTYn.

Comment: Could you upload and share your entire kernel .config that worked in the end? I have a similar problem with a chromium kernel for ARM. Thanks!

Comment: @DanieleTesta [Here you go!](https://gist.github.com/seamus-x/cfe089c574c4a6afa6084e5495439968) Just note that this is specific to eve hardware.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Chromebook developer documentation](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices), the Eve is [Intel x86_64 Kabylake-Y](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/design/personal-computers/platforms/kaby-lake-u-y/overview.html) hardware. So it probably uses the `i915` display driver, which uses kernel modesetting.

I'm not quite sure which firmware is used in Chromebooks; if it uses Coreboot, the display hardware might remain completely uninitialized until the `i915` driver takes control of it. If it uses UEFI, you will probably need `CONFIG_FB_EFI` for early boot messages.

From the help text of the `CONFIG_DRM_FBDEV_EMULATION` kernel configuration option (emphasis mine):

> CONFIG_DRM_FBDEV_EMULATION:
>
> Choose this option if you have a need for the legacy fbdev support. **Note that this support also provides the linux console support on top of your modesetting driver**.
>
> If in doubt, say "Y".

Also check the `CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE` option; it's definitely necessary too.

If the drivers are in order, you would also need to have the `getty@tty3.service` starting automatically for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. Normally `systemd` will do this automatically if `/dev/tty0` exists (i.e. the kernel virtual console subsystem has successfully activated - it is actually optional, which may surprise people used to x86 PC hardware) and no other system is taking over the `/dev/tty[1-6]` devices.

I suspect your problem might be that you don't have `CONFIG_DRM_FBDEV_EMULATION`, so there will be no `/dev/tty0` and so the `getty` processes for the text console(s) won't get launched by `systemd`.

Since Chromebook apparently has no PC-style BIOS, there will be no VGA text console either, and so `CONFIG_VGA_CONSOLE` will do absolutely nothing.

Comment: Do chromebooks use `systemd`?

Comment: The original poster said he's using **Debian 10** on a Chromebook, and Debian 10 uses `systemd` by default.

Comment: Thanks, missed it ;-)

Comment: @telcoM Thanks! Still haven't gotten this figured out yet, and I'm pretty sure I checked everything pertaining to console, TTY, and framebuffer... however, this may not be a kernel configuration problem at all, as when I tried the same kernel on Ubuntu, the opposite thing happened: DM failed to launch, but I was able to access TTY.